# How do you get the vendor and product IDs for a USB device in a kernel extension?

Tags: macos, usb, device-driver, iokit, kernel-extension

i am writing a kernel extension for mac os to load when mass storage device is attached to machine.

i create for plist file is working perfectly, it loads a kernel extension when mass storage device is connected to machine but i want to find out connected device vendor id and product id for specific purpose please help..

Comment: In what context do you "want to find out" the VID/PID? Kext code? Shell script? User space C code? Given what information? An IOUSBInterface instance?

Comment: i want to find in kext code of connected device VID/PID.

Comment: OK, I've provided some sample code in my answer. In case you were planning to use this to select only certain devices your driver should be loaded for, I've also explained how to do that - this isn't done in your kext's code, but in the `IOKitPersonalities` dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading the kext for certain VID/PID combinations**

If you want your kext only to be loaded for devices a certain VID/PID combination, you should extend your IOKit personality dictionaries. Apple documents the full rules for USB devices/interfaces in [QA1076](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1076/_index.html), but essentially, you need to add integer properties for `idVendor` and `idProduct` to the personalities in your Info.plist:

```
<key>idVendor</key>
<integer>1234</integer>
<key>idProduct</key>
<integer>5678</key>
```

*Note that you will need to convert IDs from hexadecimal to decimal.*

If you need to support multiple product IDs, you can use `idProductArray` instead of `idProduct`. The value for this property is an array containing integers.

**Accessing Vendor/Product ID programmatically in the kext**

If you need the VID/PID information to influence your code flow in some way, you can query the idVendor/idProduct properties directly on the device or interface object. For example let's say you want to do this in your driver instance's `start()` function:

```
bool MyKext::start(IOService* provider)
{
    // …
    // call to superclass's start(), etc.
    // …

    // Fetch vendor ID:
    OSNumber* vid_num = OSDynamicCast(OSNumber, provider->getProperty(kUSBVendorID));
    if (vid_num != nullptr)
    {
        uint32_t vid = vid_num->unsigned32BitValue();
        // use vid here
    }
    // …
}
```

You can similarly replace `kUSBVendorID` with `kUSBProductId` to query the product ID.

Comment: "Accessing Vendor/Product ID programmatically in the kext "  this one is work for me,Thanks.